# In layers panel, how do I show only layers belonging to the current artboard?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

In Illustrator, I have 12 artboards and dozens of layers, and they are all mixing up.

In layers panel, how do I show only layers belonging to the current artboard?

Do I need to assign layers to artboards first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they're on the artboard, use the move tool to select everything on the artboard. In the layers panel all selected layers will have a box next to them. You can group these and turn off all other layers then ungroup to work on.